# How to track down a "double free or corruption" error

Tags: c++, c, debugging, free

When I run my (C++) program it crashes with this error.

> *** glibc detected *** ./load: double free or corruption (!prev):
>   0x0000000000c6ed50 ***

How can I track down the error?

I tried using print (`std::cout`) statements, without success. Could `gdb` make this easier?

Comment: I wonder why everybody suggests to `NULL` pointers (which masks errors which are otherwise caught, as this question nicely shows), but nobody suggests to simply not to do manual memory management at all, which is very well possible in C++. I haven't written `delete` in years. (And, yes, my code is performance-critical. Otherwise it wouldn't have been written in C++.)

Comment: @sbi: Heap corruption and the like are rarely caught, at least not where they happen. `NULL`ing pointers might make your program crash earlier.

Comment: @Hasturkun: I strongly disagree. A major incentive to `NULL` pointers is to prevent a second `delete ptr;` from blowing up - which is masking an error, because that second `delete` should never have been happening. (It's also used to check whether a pointer is still pointing to a valid object. But that just raises the question why you have a pointer in scope that doesn't have an object to point to.)

Comment: I think all the answers below which suggest "manually" looking for pointer problems and NULLing them etc are bad bandaids. Learning to use any of the real tools to find these problems is invaluable. In the case of Valgrind, it can be as easy as apt-get install valgrind and prefixing your program with valgrind and an option (as one of the answers below show).

Answer (score 83):

If you're using glibc, you can set the `MALLOC_CHECK_` environment variable to `2`, this will cause glibc to use an error tolerant version of `malloc`, which will cause your program to abort at the point where the double free is done.

You can set this from gdb by using the `set environment MALLOC_CHECK_ 2` command before running your program; the program should abort, with the `free()` call visible in the backtrace.

see the [man page for `malloc()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/malloc) for more information

Comment: Setting `MALLOC_CHECK_2` actually fixed my double free problem (although it's not fixing if it's in debug mode only)

Comment: @puk I have the same issue, setting MALLOC_CHECK_ to 2 does avoid my double-free problem. What other options there to inject as less as code to reproduce issue and provide a backtrace?

Comment: Also have it where setting MALLOC_CHECK_ avoids the problem. Fellow commenters/anyone...did you figure out a different way to exhibit the problem?

Comment: " When MALLOC_CHECK_ is set to a non-zero value, a special (less efficient) implementation is used which is designed to be tolerant against simple errors, such as double calls of free with the same argument, or overruns of a single byte (off-by-one bugs)." https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Heap-Consistency-Checking.html So it seems like MALLOC_CHECK_ is only used to avoid simple memory errors, not detect them.

Comment: Actually.... https://support.microfocus.com/kb/doc.php?id=3113982 seems like setting MALLOC_CHECK_ to 3 is the most useful and can be used to detect errors.

Answer (score 39):

There are at least two possible situations:

1. you are deleting the same entity twice
2. you are deleting something that wasn't allocated

For the first one I strongly suggest NULL-ing all deleted pointers.

You have three options:

1. overload new and delete and track the allocations
2. yes, use gdb -- then you'll get a backtrace from your crash, and that'll probably be very helpful
3. as suggested -- use Valgrind -- it isn't easy to get into, but it will save you time thousandfold in the future...

Comment: 2. would cause corruption, but I don't think this message would generally appear, since the sanity checking is only done on the heap.  However, I think 3. heap buffer overflow is possible.

Comment: Good one. True i missed to make the pointer NULL and faced with this error. Lessons learnt!

Answer (score 32):

You can use gdb, but I would first try [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/).  See the [quick start guide](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/QuickStart.html).

Briefly, Valgrind instruments your program so it can detect several kinds of errors in using dynamically allocated memory, such as double frees and writes past the end of allocated blocks of memory (which can corrupt the heap). It detects and reports the errors  *as soon as they occur*, thus pointing you directly to the cause of the problem.

Comment: @SMR, in this case the essential parts of the answer is the whole, big, linked page. So including just the link in the answer is perfectly fine. A few words about why the author prefers Valgrind over gdb and how he would tackle the _specific_ problem is IMHO what's really missing from the answer.

Comment: One can also use lldb if they prefer llvm over gnu.

Comment: for me error was in freeing memory correctly allocated to a pointer that was correctly set up (not NULL) and the correctly freed - only once and not twice... Valgrind showed up that a different pointer had the incorrect amount of memory allocated..., which led to the error message above... - fixed the incorrect allocation for a completely different pointer and problem solved.  many thanks for the helpful answer :-)

Answer (score 27):

Three basic rules:

1. Set pointer to `NULL` after free
2. Check for `NULL` before freeing.
3. Initialise pointer to `NULL` in the start.

Combination of these three works quite well.

Comment: I'm not C expert, but I usually can keep my head above water.  Why #1?  Is it just so your program flat out crashes when you try and access a free'd pointer, and not just a silent error?

Comment: @Precision: Yes, that's the point. It is a good practice: having a pointer to deleted memory is a risk.

Comment: @ereOn: Thanks.  I've just had a couple classes on C, and never had to write code that with anyone else, so never really had this problem.  Seems like a very good practice though.

Comment: Strictly speaking I think #2 is unnecessary as most compilers will allow you to try to delete a null pointer without this causing a problem. I'm sure someone will correct me if I'm wrong. :)

Comment: @Component10 I think that freeing NULL is required by the C standard to do nothing.

Comment: @Demetri: Yes, you're right *"if the value of the operand of delete is the null pointer the operation has no effect." (ISO/IEC 14882:2003(E) 5.3.5.2)*

Answer (score 20):

With modern C++ compilers you can use **sanitizers** to track.

Sample example :

My program:

```
$cat d_free.cxx 
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()

{
   int * i = new int();
   delete i;
   //i = NULL;
   delete i;
}
```

Compile with address sanitizers :

```
# g++-7.1 d_free.cxx -Wall -Werror -fsanitize=address -g
```

Execute :

```
# ./a.out 
=================================================================
==4836==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: attempting double-free on 0x602000000010 in thread T0:
    #0 0x7f35b2d7b3c8 in operator delete(void*, unsigned long) /media/sf_shared/gcc-7.1.0/libsanitizer/asan/asan_new_delete.cc:140
    #1 0x400b2c in main /media/sf_shared/jkr/cpp/d_free/d_free.cxx:11
    #2 0x7f35b2050c04 in __libc_start_main (/lib64/libc.so.6+0x21c04)
    #3 0x400a08  (/media/sf_shared/jkr/cpp/d_free/a.out+0x400a08)

0x602000000010 is located 0 bytes inside of 4-byte region [0x602000000010,0x602000000014)
freed by thread T0 here:
    #0 0x7f35b2d7b3c8 in operator delete(void*, unsigned long) /media/sf_shared/gcc-7.1.0/libsanitizer/asan/asan_new_delete.cc:140
    #1 0x400b1b in main /media/sf_shared/jkr/cpp/d_free/d_free.cxx:9
    #2 0x7f35b2050c04 in __libc_start_main (/lib64/libc.so.6+0x21c04)

previously allocated by thread T0 here:
    #0 0x7f35b2d7a040 in operator new(unsigned long) /media/sf_shared/gcc-7.1.0/libsanitizer/asan/asan_new_delete.cc:80
    #1 0x400ac9 in main /media/sf_shared/jkr/cpp/d_free/d_free.cxx:8
    #2 0x7f35b2050c04 in __libc_start_main (/lib64/libc.so.6+0x21c04)

SUMMARY: AddressSanitizer: double-free /media/sf_shared/gcc-7.1.0/libsanitizer/asan/asan_new_delete.cc:140 in operator delete(void*, unsigned long)
==4836==ABORTING
```

To learn more about sanitizers you can check [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MB6NPkB4YVs) or [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V2_80g0eOMc&t=554s) or any modern c++ compilers (e.g. gcc, clang etc.) documentations.

Answer (score 18):

You can use `valgrind` to debug it.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main()
{
 char *x = malloc(100);
 free(x);
 free(x);
 return 0;
}

[sand@PS-CNTOS-64-S11 testbox]$ vim t1.c
[sand@PS-CNTOS-64-S11 testbox]$ cc -g t1.c -o t1
[sand@PS-CNTOS-64-S11 testbox]$ ./t1
*** glibc detected *** ./t1: double free or corruption (top): 0x00000000058f7010 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib64/libc.so.6[0x3a3127245f]
/lib64/libc.so.6(cfree+0x4b)[0x3a312728bb]
./t1[0x400500]
/lib64/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf4)[0x3a3121d994]
./t1[0x400429]
======= Memory map: ========
00400000-00401000 r-xp 00000000 68:02 30246184                           /home/sand/testbox/t1
00600000-00601000 rw-p 00000000 68:02 30246184                           /home/sand/testbox/t1
058f7000-05918000 rw-p 058f7000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
3a30e00000-3a30e1c000 r-xp 00000000 68:03 5308733                        /lib64/ld-2.5.so
3a3101b000-3a3101c000 r--p 0001b000 68:03 5308733                        /lib64/ld-2.5.so
3a3101c000-3a3101d000 rw-p 0001c000 68:03 5308733                        /lib64/ld-2.5.so
3a31200000-3a3134e000 r-xp 00000000 68:03 5310248                        /lib64/libc-2.5.so
3a3134e000-3a3154e000 ---p 0014e000 68:03 5310248                        /lib64/libc-2.5.so
3a3154e000-3a31552000 r--p 0014e000 68:03 5310248                        /lib64/libc-2.5.so
3a31552000-3a31553000 rw-p 00152000 68:03 5310248                        /lib64/libc-2.5.so
3a31553000-3a31558000 rw-p 3a31553000 00:00 0
3a41c00000-3a41c0d000 r-xp 00000000 68:03 5310264                        /lib64/libgcc_s-4.1.2-20080825.so.1
3a41c0d000-3a41e0d000 ---p 0000d000 68:03 5310264                        /lib64/libgcc_s-4.1.2-20080825.so.1
3a41e0d000-3a41e0e000 rw-p 0000d000 68:03 5310264                        /lib64/libgcc_s-4.1.2-20080825.so.1
2b1912300000-2b1912302000 rw-p 2b1912300000 00:00 0
2b191231c000-2b191231d000 rw-p 2b191231c000 00:00 0
7ffffe214000-7ffffe229000 rw-p 7ffffffe9000 00:00 0                      [stack]
7ffffe2b0000-7ffffe2b4000 r-xp 7ffffe2b0000 00:00 0                      [vdso]
ffffffffff600000-ffffffffffe00000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0                  [vsyscall]
Aborted
[sand@PS-CNTOS-64-S11 testbox]$


[sand@PS-CNTOS-64-S11 testbox]$ vim t1.c
[sand@PS-CNTOS-64-S11 testbox]$ cc -g t1.c -o t1
[sand@PS-CNTOS-64-S11 testbox]$ valgrind --tool=memcheck ./t1
==20859== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==20859== Copyright (C) 2002-2009, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==20859== Using Valgrind-3.5.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==20859== Command: ./t1
==20859==
==20859== Invalid free() / delete / delete[]
==20859==    at 0x4A05A31: free (vg_replace_malloc.c:325)
==20859==    by 0x4004FF: main (t1.c:8)
==20859==  Address 0x4c26040 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 100 free'd
==20859==    at 0x4A05A31: free (vg_replace_malloc.c:325)
==20859==    by 0x4004F6: main (t1.c:7)
==20859==
==20859==
==20859== HEAP SUMMARY:
==20859==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==20859==   total heap usage: 1 allocs, 2 frees, 100 bytes allocated
==20859==
==20859== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==20859==
==20859== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==20859== ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 4 from 4)
[sand@PS-CNTOS-64-S11 testbox]$


[sand@PS-CNTOS-64-S11 testbox]$ valgrind --tool=memcheck --leak-check=full ./t1
==20899== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==20899== Copyright (C) 2002-2009, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==20899== Using Valgrind-3.5.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==20899== Command: ./t1
==20899==
==20899== Invalid free() / delete / delete[]
==20899==    at 0x4A05A31: free (vg_replace_malloc.c:325)
==20899==    by 0x4004FF: main (t1.c:8)
==20899==  Address 0x4c26040 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 100 free'd
==20899==    at 0x4A05A31: free (vg_replace_malloc.c:325)
==20899==    by 0x4004F6: main (t1.c:7)
==20899==
==20899==
==20899== HEAP SUMMARY:
==20899==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==20899==   total heap usage: 1 allocs, 2 frees, 100 bytes allocated
==20899==
==20899== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==20899==
==20899== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==20899== ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 4 from 4)
[sand@PS-CNTOS-64-S11 testbox]$
```

One possible fix:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main()
{
 char *x = malloc(100);
 free(x);
 x=NULL;
 free(x);
 return 0;
}

[sand@PS-CNTOS-64-S11 testbox]$ vim t1.c
[sand@PS-CNTOS-64-S11 testbox]$ cc -g t1.c -o t1
[sand@PS-CNTOS-64-S11 testbox]$ ./t1
[sand@PS-CNTOS-64-S11 testbox]$

[sand@PS-CNTOS-64-S11 testbox]$ valgrind --tool=memcheck --leak-check=full ./t1
==20958== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==20958== Copyright (C) 2002-2009, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==20958== Using Valgrind-3.5.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==20958== Command: ./t1
==20958==
==20958==
==20958== HEAP SUMMARY:
==20958==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==20958==   total heap usage: 1 allocs, 1 frees, 100 bytes allocated
==20958==
==20958== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==20958==
==20958== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==20958== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 4 from 4)
[sand@PS-CNTOS-64-S11 testbox]$
```

Check out the blog on using Valgrind [Link](http://debuggingdoublefreecorruption.blogspot.com.au/)

Comment: My program takes about 30 minutes to run, on Valgrind it can take 18 to 20 hours to finish.

Answer (score 5):

Are you using smart pointers such as Boost `shared_ptr`? If so, check if you are directly using the raw pointer anywhere by calling `get()`. I've found this to be quite a common problem.

For example, imagine a scenario where a raw pointer is passed (maybe as a callback handler, say) to your code. You might decide to assign this to a smart pointer in order to cope with reference counting etc. Big mistake: your code doesn't own this pointer unless you take a deep copy. When your code is done with the smart pointer it will destroy it and attempt to destroy the memory it points to since it *thinks* that no-one else needs it, *but* the calling code will then try to delete it and you'll get a double free problem.

Of course, that might not be your problem here. At it's simplest here's an example which shows how it can happen. The first delete is fine but the compiler senses that it's already deleted that memory and causes a problem. That's why assigning 0 to a pointer immediately after deletion is a good idea.

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    char* ptr = new char[20];

    delete[] ptr;
    ptr = 0;  // Comment me out and watch me crash and burn.
    delete[] ptr;
}
```

Edit: changed `delete` to `delete[]`, as ptr is an array of char.

Comment: I didn't use any delete commands in my program. Could this still be the problem?

Comment: @Phenom: Why did you not use deletes? Is it because you're using smart pointers? Presumably you are using new in your code to create objects on the heap? If the answer to both of these is yes then are you using get / set on the smart pointers to copy around raw pointers? If so, don't! You'd be breaking the reference counting. Alternatively you could be assigning a pointer from library code you're calling to a smart pointer. If you don't 'own' the memory pointed to then don't do it, as the both the library and the smart pointer will try to delete it.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was linking my program against `CUDA 10.0` while a dependency of my program was linked with `CUDA 10.2 (cudart.10.2.so)`. The inconsistency caused "double free or corruption" for me.

You can use `ldd <your program>` to see if there are more than one version of CUDA libs in the dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error, mine was due to corruption. I thought I was freeing a pointer pointing to a memory allocated with malloc but in reality, it was on the stack.

Answer (score -4):

I know this is a very old thread, but it is the top google search for this error, and none of the responses mention a common cause of the error.

Which is closing a file you've already closed.

If you're not paying attention and have two different functions close the same file, then the second one will generate this error.

Comment: You are incorrect, this error is thrown due to a double free, exactly as the error states. The fact that you're closing a file twice is causing a double free as clearly the close method is trying to free the same data twice.