# Finding allocation site for double-free errors (with valgrind)

Tags: linux, valgrind

Given a double-free error (reported by valgrind), is there a way to find out where the memory was allocated? Valgrind only tells me the location of the deallocation site (i.e. the call to `free()`), but I would like to know where the memory was **allocated**.

Comment: You could instrument your code in the build you use for Valgrind checks and make sure to take note of allocations and frees. However, with `--error-limit=no --track-origins=yes` I was so far always able to deduce the origin, given the call stacks.

Comment: I was able to track down this particular problem by using the glibc malloc hooks described in http://www.gnu.org/s/hello/manual/libc/Hooks-for-Malloc.html. Neither `--error-limit=no` or `--track-origins=yes` gave any useful info, but the malloc hooks together with some semi-intelligent guesswork allowed me to figure out the problem. But I guess the question still stands, even if I've solved this problem.

Comment: basically I asked some time ago on the mailing list why various kinds of backtracking the way you want it (and I wanted it) are not possible. The reasoning was that there would be way too many false positives and in many cases the results would be very inconclusive. Thus I doubt the feature you want exists as such. Even if that's not the answer you'd like to hear ;)

Comment: This is _not_ a Linux-specific question... The "linux" tag is not appropriate.

Answer (score 14):

To get Valgrind keep tracks of allocation stack traces, you have to use options:

```
--track-origins=yes --keep-stacktraces=alloc-and-free
```

Valgrind will then report allocation stack under `Block was alloc'd at` section, just after `Address ... inside a block of size x free'd` alert.

In case your application is large, `--error-limit=no --num-callers=40` options may be useful too.

Answer (score 1):

The first check I would do is verifying that the error is indeed due to a double-free error. Sometimes, running a program (including with valgrind) can show a double-free error while in reality, it's a memory corruption problem (for example a memory overflow).

The best way to check is to apply the advice detailed in the answers : [How to track down a double free or corruption error in C++ with gdb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2902064/how-to-track-down-a-double-free-or-corruption-error-in-c-with-gdb/2903152).

First of all, you can try to compile your program with flags `fsanitize=address -g`. This will instrument the memory of the program at runtime to keep track of all allocations, detect overflows, etc.

In any case, if the problem is indeed a double-free, the error message should contain all the necessary information for you to debug the problem.