# GlibC Double free or corruption (fclose)

Tags: free, glibc, corruption, fclose

I got an error on my C program on runtime. I found some stuff about "double free or corruption" error but nothing relevant.

Here is my code :

```
void compute_crc32(const char* filename, unsigned long * destination)
{
  FILE* tmp_chunk = fopen(filename, "rb");
  printf("\n\t\t\tCalculating CRC...");
  fflush(stdout);
  Crc32_ComputeFile(tmp_chunk, destination);
  printf("\t[0x%08lX]", *destination);
  fflush(stdout);
  fclose(tmp_chunk);
  printf("\t[ OK ]");
  fflush(stdout);
}
```

It seems the

```
fclose(tmp_chunk);
```

raises this glibc error :

```
*** glibc detected *** ./crc32: double free or corruption (out): 0x09ed86f0 ***

======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x75ee2)[0xb763cee2]
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(fclose+0x154)[0xb762c424]
./crc32[0x80498be]
./crc32[0x8049816]
./crc32[0x804919c]
./crc32[0x8049cc2]
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf3)[0xb75e04d3]
./crc32[0x8048961]
```

In the console output, the last CRC is displayed but not the last "[ OK ]"...

I never have this type of error and I searched for hours on Google but nothing really interesting in my case... please help :)

---

Now I have another error :

```
*** glibc detected *** ./xsplit: free(): invalid next size (normal): 0x095a66f0 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x75ee2)[0xb7647ee2]
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(fclose+0x154)[0xb7637424]
./xsplit[0x80497f7]
./xsplit[0x804919c]
./xsplit[0x8049cd6]
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf3)[0xb75eb4d3]
./xsplit[0x8048961]
```

What the hell is this ? I'm lost... :(

Comment: Don't you have another fclose in Crc32_ComputeFile? It would explain everything.

Comment: no I already searched that. The "Crc32_ComputeFile" takes a FILE pointer on an opened file and a reference to an unsigned long for the output CRC checksum

Comment: I just think the **out** word in the glibc error makes a sense... I will test something...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to track down a double free or corruption error in C++ with gdb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2902064/how-to-track-down-a-double-free-or-corruption-error-in-c-with-gdb)

Answer (score 2):

> `*** glibc detected *** ./crc32: double free or corruption`

Glibc is telling you that you've corrupted heap.

*The* tools to find such corruption on Linux are [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org) and [AddressSanitizer](http://code.google.com/p/address-sanitizer/wiki/AddressSanitizer).

Chances are, either one of them will immediately tell you what your problem is.

Comment: Program doesn't crash when runned through valgrind... I don't know why :'(

Comment: @MikeChoko "doesn't crash" -- that's ok. Does Valgrind report any errors?