# double free or corruption (fasttop)

Tags: c, linked-list, coredump, double-free

The following section of my code gives me this messege when executing *** glibc detected**  ./a.out: double free or corruption (fasttop): 0x08e065d0 **

i have gone through the code many times but i cant clealry see how i am misusing the `free (temp2)`

```
bool found= false;
int x=0;
for ( x=0; x<=312500; x++)
{
    while (count <=32)
    {
        fscanf (file, "%d", &temp->num);  

        temp->ptr=NULL;

        newNode = (NODE *)malloc(sizeof(NODE));
        newNode->num=temp->num;
        newNode->ptr=NULL;

        if (first != NULL)
        {
            temp2=(NODE *)malloc(sizeof(NODE));

            temp2=first;
            while (temp2 != NULL && !found)
            {
                if (temp2->num == newNode->num) 
                {found=true;}

                temp2= temp2->ptr;
            }

            free(temp2);

            if (!found)
            { 
                last->ptr=newNode;
                last=newNode;
                count=count+1;
            }   
        }   
        else  
        {
            first = newNode;
            last = newNode;
            count=count+1;
        }

        fflush(stdin);
    }
```

Comment: What is the _purpose_ of this program fragment ? BTW: `temp2=(NODE *)malloc(sizeof(NODE)); temp2=first;` will _at least_ leak memory.

Comment: You should check (first->ptr) != NULL

Comment: fflush have undefined behavior. If you want to discard data on stdin, read them and discard but avoid the usage of fflush.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to track down a "double free or corruption" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2902064/how-to-track-down-a-double-free-or-corruption-error)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
        temp2=first;
```

Basically, when you free temp2, you free first, not the memory allocated here:

```
        temp2=(NODE *)malloc(sizeof(NODE));
```

, which remains a memory leak, because after the assignment it can't be freed anymore.

Also, your code has probably some more problems (one is that you shouldn't use `fflush` on an input stream), but without some more details, it's impossible to tell.

Comment: @Abhineet: I don't think Paul92 meant to; to me it looks like he just made a typo. He meant to write *shouldn't* but didn't hit the `n`. So what came out was *should't* which you read as *should*.