# double free or corruption 3d array in C

Tags: c, arrays, malloc, free, corruption

I get a 'double free or corruption' error while freeing up an 3d array. Can anyone please tell me where is the problem in the code? **The size of the array is 2*N*N. Value of N here is 100. Even without casting, same result.**
Here is the code:

```
// Mallocing 
double ***h = malloc(2 * (sizeof(double**)));
for(i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    h[i] = malloc(N * sizeof(double*));
    for(j = 0; j < N; j++) {
        h[i][j] = malloc(N * sizeof(double));
    }
}

// Freeing
for(i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    for(j = 0; j < N; j++) {
        free(h[i][j]);
    }
    free(h[i]);
}
free(h);
```

The program works fine but at the end I get an error 'double free or corruption (!prev): 0x08cd24f8'
Aborted (core dumped).

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: What is the value of `N`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to track down a double free or corruption error in C++ with gdb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2902064/how-to-track-down-a-double-free-or-corruption-error-in-c-with-gdb)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first dimension, you allocate 2 elements:

```
double ***h = (double***) malloc(2 * (sizeof(double**)));
```

But you treat it as if it had `N` elements:

```
for(i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    h[i] = ...
```

Change outermost loop comparison on allocation **and** free to:

```
for(i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
```

Also don't cast return value of `malloc`. Also, your code is missing error handling, and will break if allocation fails.

Answer (score 1):

As fas as I can see you allocate 2 items, then fill N of them.

```
double ***h = (double***) malloc(2 * (sizeof(double**)));
for(i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    h[i] = (double**) malloc(N * sizeof(double*));
    ....
    ....
}
```

You're overwriting not allocated space if N>2...

Answer (score 0):

The problem's here:

```
double ***h = (double***) malloc(2 * (sizeof(double**)));
for(i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    // ...
}
```

You only `malloc` 2 elements, and iterate over `N`.
I guess you wanted to have array of size `N*N*N`, but you ended up with `2*N*N` instead.

So this:

```
double ***h = (double***) malloc(2 * (sizeof(double**)));
```

Should be:

```
double ***h = (double***) malloc(N * (sizeof(double**)));
```

Comment: Its a 2*N*N array,  not N*N*N.

Answer (score 0):

If the value of `N = 100` as in your comment then you need to allocate memory to hold N pointer-to-pointer where you have just 2 .

```
double ***h =  malloc(N * (sizeof(double*)));
```

Don't cast `malloc()`

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, the specific problem causing the bug is you treating the dimension with 2 elements as if it had N elements.

The core reason for this however, is obfuscation. There are some rules I would strongly recommend you to follow:

- Always allocate multi-dimensional arrays as *true arrays allocated in adjacent memory*. [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12462615/how-do-i-correctly-set-up-access-and-free-a-multidimensional-array-in-c).
- Never allocate multi-dimensional arrays as pointer-to-pointer based lookup-tables that are fragmented all over the heap. Not only are they slower and make the code harder to read, they aren't actually arrays. You can't use them together with `memcpy()` etc.

  Unfortunately there are countless of bad C programming teachers and bad books that preach fragmented pointer-to-pointer lookup-tables. So many programmers have to unlearn this, it is frightening...
- Never use more than two levels of indirection in your program. There should never be a reason to do so, all it does is to turn your program less readable (Reference MISRA-C:2012 rule 18.5). This is actually known as "three star programming" and it's not a flattering term.
- Never cast the result of malloc, because [it is pointless to do so](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).

What you *should* do:

```
double (*array)[Y][Z] = malloc( sizeof(double[X][Y][Z]) );
...
free(array);
```

Example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define X 2
#define Y 3
#define Z 4

int main (void)
{
  double (*array)[Y][Z] = malloc( sizeof(double[X][Y][Z]) );

  double count = 0.0;
  for(int x=0; x<X; x++)
  {
    for(int y=0; y<Y; y++)
    {
      for(int z=0; z<Z; z++)
      {
        array[x][y][z] = count++;
        printf("%f ", array[x][y][z]);
      }
      printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n");
  }

  free(array);

  return 0;
}
```

To compile this, you need a compiler which is not older than 16 years.

Comment: Thank you very much for the valuable input. You provided really good points in there. Cheers