# How to catch or handle segfault from free() or delete()

Tags: c++, linux

In c++, I have a server code running continuously 24*7 but i am getting segfault sometimes while freeing the buffer.
I tried **try catch** as well.

```
        try {
                    free(partialBuf);
                } catch (...) {
                    printf("Caught partial buf free error");
                }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `try`, `catch` in `c`? no? in `c++`? why `free()`? why not `delete`?

Comment: You can't _catch_ a segfault.

Comment: You **shouldn't** try to handle a segfault. It's a bug, find the cause and fix it! It's not something you should casually dismiss as *ok*. That being said, if i'm not mistaken a segfault is a signal `SIGSEGV` - read about signal handling in c, and you might be able to ignore it. But it will just bring more pain later.

Comment: `How to catch or handle segfault`... run through debugger and fix the code. Best and easiest way.

Comment: @jepio beat me by 10 secs. :-)

Comment: Can you please explain why its a null pointer exception? @user4559929

Comment: Segmentation fault is mainly caused by attempt to access or manipulate a null pointer.

Comment: @SouravGhosh i tried delete as well instead of free. what i learned on internet are delete mostly call's deconstructor and free() will directly free the address we provided.

Comment: @user4559929 or better to say, _invalid_ pointer. :-)

Comment: There's no such "null pointer exception" in C. It's a plain crash.

Comment: What's your question exactly? Is it "how do I debug a segfault?" Also, why is this tagged `C`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're apparently able to use `try/catch`, you're writing C++ code. It helps to know which language you're using.

The solution then is to use `std::shared_ptr`. You may have multiple places in which a pointer goes out of scope. With `shared_ptr` you no longer call `free`, **and** as a bonus `shared_ptr` will call `delete` only once (after the last pointer goes out of scope).

However, you should now allocate memory with `new` instead of `malloc`.

Answer (score 0):

A segfault is not an exception in the sense of other C++ exceptions, hence you cannot catch it with `try`/`catch`. A segfault can have any number of reasons, but in 99.9% of cases it's a memory access bug :-) If the segfault happens during a call to `delete` or `free()`, chances are that you are having a [double-free](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2902064/how-to-track-down-a-double-free-or-corruption-error-in-c-with-gdb) issue.

Comment: Thanks.But is there any way to know that whether pointer got freed before calling free() or its memory still accessible ??

Comment: Yes. Use valgrind or a similar tool.

Answer (score 0):

You could use GDB to debug, and find out whether you are trying to free a pointer which was not allocated previously.