# random double free or corruption (out) C

Tags: c

I'm facing a problem which is driving me crazy !

I have a function, this one :

```
void    load_weapons3(t_env *e, char *name, int x, t_weapon *w)
{
    char    *tmp;
    char    *fname;
    t_image i;

    fname = NULL;
    tmp = NULL;
    tmp = ft_get_name_without_extention(name);
    if (!tmp)
        return ;
    fname = ft_strcat(tmp, "_fire.xpm");
    free(tmp);
    if (!fname)
        return ;
    i.image = mlx_xpm_file_to_image(e->mlx_ptr, fname, &(i.x), &(i.y));
    if (!i.image)
    {
        (*w).fire = NULL;
        return ;
    }
    else
        (*w).fire = malloc(sizeof(t_weaponfire) * QTY_OF_FIRE);
    i.image_data = mlx_get_data_addr(i.image,
                                        &(i.bpp),
                                        &(i.size_line),
                                        &(i.endian));
    i.image_tab = get_image_tab(i);
    load_weapon_fire(e, x, i);
    printf("%s\n", fname);
    free(fname);
}
```

Other parts of code that may be relevant :

```
int     ft_strlen(char *str)
{
    int     i;

    i = 0;
    while (str[i])
        i++;
    return (i);
}

char    *ft_strcpy(char *str)
{
    int     i;
    int     j;
    char    *cpystr;

    j = 0;
    i = ft_strlen(str);
    cpystr = malloc(sizeof(char) * (i + 1));
    while (j < i)
    {
        cpystr[j] = str[j];
        j++;
    }
    cpystr[j] = '\0';
    return (cpystr);
}
char    *ft_get_name_without_extention(char *fullpath)
{
    char    *str;
    int     i;

    i = ft_strlen(fullpath);
    str = ft_strcpy(fullpath);
    while (i)
    {
        if (str[i] == '.')
        {
            str[i] = '\0';
            return (str);
        }
        i--;
    }
    free(str);
    return (NULL);
}

char    *ft_strcat(char *str1, char *str2)
{
    int     i;
    int     len1;
    int     len2;
    char    *str;

    i = 0;
    str = NULL;
    if (!str1 || !str2)
        return (NULL);
    len1 = ft_strlen(str1);
    len2 = ft_strlen(str2);
    str = malloc(sizeof(char) * (len1 + len2 + 1));
    if (!str)
        return (NULL);
    while (i < len1)
        str[i] = str1[i++];
    len1 = 0;
    while (len1 < len2)
        str[i + len1] = str2[len1++];
    str[i + len1] = '\0';
    return (str);
}

void    load_weapons(t_env *e)
{
    int             xpm_q;
    DIR             *d;
    struct dirent   *dir;

    xpm_q = ft_get_xpm_quantity("img/weapons");
    printf("Xpm_q is : %d\n", xpm_q);
    if (xpm_q > 0)
    {
        e->weapons.weapons_count = xpm_q;
        e->weapons.weapons = malloc(sizeof(t_image) * (xpm_q + 1));
        xpm_q--;
        d = opendir("img/weapons");
        if (d)
        {
            while ((dir = readdir(d)) != NULL)
            {
                load_weapons2(&xpm_q, &(e->weapons.weapons[xpm_q]), e, dir->d_name);
            }
            closedir(d);
        }
    }
    e->weapons.selected_weapon = 0;
}

void    load_weapons2(int *xpm_quantity, t_weapon *w, t_env *e, char *n)
{
    char    *fname;
    t_image *i;

    if (!ft_have_extension(".xpm\0", n) || ft_have_extension("_fire.xpm\0", n))
        return ;
    i = &(w->image);
    fname = ft_strcat("img/weapons/", n);
    i->name = ft_strcpy(n);
    i->image = mlx_xpm_file_to_image(e->mlx_ptr, fname, &(i->x), &(i->y));
    i->image_data = mlx_get_data_addr(i->image,
                                            &(i->bpp),
                                                &(i->size_line),
                                                    &(i->endian));
    i->image_tab = get_image_tab((*i));
    load_weapons3(e, fname, *xpm_quantity, w);
    free(fname);
    (*xpm_quantity)--;
}
```

And sometimes (really randomly) I get a "double free or corruption (out)", that appears to occur when I free fname pointer. The fact is I'm not double freeing it, and printf prints it without any problem...

If someone has a clue...

I'm using gcc (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04) 4.8.4, running in VirtualBox.

Thanks for reading !

Comment: You should post *all* relevant code. For example, *does* `ft_get_name_without_extention()` allocate a buffer big enough to concatenate `"_fire.xpm"` without overflowing?

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to do, but try removing `if (fname)
        free(fname);` as `fname` wasn't allocated by `malloc` or family.

Comment: where did you allocate memory to `fname` ?

Comment: @CoolGuy, ameyCU: `fname` is the same as `tmp` after `ft_strcat()`, provided it works like `strcat()` and `tmp != 0` before, otherwise the test for `if (!fname)` comes too late.

Comment: Does `ft_get_name_without_extention()` allocate memory?  What is returned if it fails?  Can `ft_strcat()` take a null pointer, and if so, what does it do?  Also, does `ft_strcat()` allocate any memory?

Comment: @EOF  If that's the case then why freeing both `tmp` and `fname` ?

Comment: Going to highly, highly recommend using `valgrind` here.  Use `--leak-check=yes` for more detailed info, check out the quick-start guide [here](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/quick-start.html).

Comment: I updated my question with more code.
If I "remove if (fname) free(fname);" everything runs fine...

Comment: @GlobCoder, thanks for posting code.  Does `ft_strcpy()` allocate, too?

Comment: @GlobCoder: No, everything is **not** fine just because you don't immediately crash after removing that bit of code. The fact that it crashes *with* the code *strongly* suggests the code is as horrifically broken as it looks. Also, sill missing code.

Comment: @GlobCoder, I have a suggestion.  To see if your stack is corrupted, print the hex value of `fname` right after allocation (returned from `ft_strcat()`) and again right before it's freed.

Comment: @donjuedo: No. Nononononono. **NO**. This sort of thing leads to madness. Just use `valgrind` or `address sanitizer`.

Comment: I reupdated my code, modifying things that wasn't tested...
I'll try with valgrind !
Thanks

Comment: @EOF, I agree that using valgrind is a great idea.  But why so much emphasis to not examine the value?  Will he go blind?  ;-)

Comment: @donjuedo: Because the pointer itself may very well point where it should. The `double free or corruption`-error indicates corruption in `malloc()`s data-structures, which are commonly in between the allocations on the heap. They are usually corrupted by out-of-bounds writes, and the error only surfaces much later, when a memory-allocation function (particularly `free()`) is called.

Comment: @EOF, Your scenario is certainly one way for things to go wrong, but not the only way.  To print values as I suggested and see a match only means to keep looking.  It's the case of a mismatch you are excluding, and I simply suggest to look.

Comment: @donjuedo: `fname`s address is never taken (meaning it could have been declared with the `register`-specifier), and it is only assigned to **once**. The compiler would be well within its rights to optimize out *any* check for a change in `fname`, since, barring undefined behavior, it **cannot** change.

Comment: And yet, I have seen it happen, which is what led to my suggestion.

Comment: It's just getting really strange...
After launching my program inside valgrind, it detected some errors and essentially one I corrected.
It was about affectation of "e->weapons.weapons[x]", saying "Address 0x6410a78 is 0 bytes after a block of size 56 alloc'd"
But I was only accessing [0], so I checked, double checked, and I still can't figure it out, but when I allocate it with one more element (a total of 2 in my case), it works...even if I'm only accessing first element ([0] of course...)
I will update with more code...

Comment: Allocation is done in load_weapons btw

Comment: @GlobCoder, Did `valgrind` say anything about "double free or corruption"?   And are you still getting that after your edits?

Comment: Recommend changing `str[i] = str1[i++];` --> `str[i] = str1[i]; i++;`

Comment: @chux Just to be sure, Doesn't `str[i] = str1[i++];` invoke UB?

Comment: @Cool Guy `Yes `str[i] = str1[i++]` is UB as it is not defined when the `i` increment occurs relative to the usage of `i` as an index.

Comment: @chux Does str[i + len1] = str2[len1++]; give UB too ? Thx for the advice !

Comment: `str[i + len1] = str2[len1++];` has the same problem as `str[i] = str1[i++]` and `foo(i) = bar(i++)`.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2902064/how-to-track-down-a-double-free-or-corruption-error-in-c-with-gdb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is horrible, and you still haven't posted your `typedef`s and `struct`-definitions, which will become relevant in the following rant:

So, in `load_weapons()`, you `malloc()` an array,

```
e->weapons.weapons = malloc(sizeof(t_image) * (xpm_q + 1));
```

the contents of which are presumably supposed to be of type `t_image`. Then you pass a pointer to the second-to-last valid object of the array to `load_weapons2()` (great, descriptive name),

```
load_weapons2(&xpm_q, &(e->weapons.weapons[xpm_q]), e, dir->d_name);
```

but wait! What was `load_weapon2()`'s prototype again?

```
void load_weapons2(int *, t_weapon *, t_env *, char *)
```

that's no `t_image*`, that's a `t_weapon*`! Shock and awe, you then *somehow* extract a `t_image*` out of a `t_weapon*` that was really a `t_image*` in the first place,

```
t_image *i;
i = &(w->image);
```

The only way that last line makes sense is if `t_weapon` has a member `t_image`, which obviously necessitates `sizeof(t_weapon) >= sizeof(t_image)`. So, unless `t_image` is the *only* member of `t_weapon`, you've allocated insufficient space.

And now for some completely unsolicited advice: **complete rewrite**.

Comment: A rewrite would certainly provide benefit.  I'd focus on descriptive names, as you pointed out, plus meaningful comments, as well as something as basic as neat formatting to help readability.  Learning to code better usually starts with some pretty rough work, and I know I've written my share.  I learned, though.

Comment: You are totally right, problem came from allocation of e->weapons.weapons, which was a t_weapon, and obviously not a t_image.
I know my code is horrible, it's a schoolwork and we must respect a norm, limitating us to 25 lines for a function and not more than 5 functions per file. So trying to shorten it makes things a little bit complicated sometimes, and even if code works, a look from outside can be very difficult...
Nevertheless, I really appreciate for your reading and precise understanding of my code.
I'll rewrite all of it for another 2D library soon.
A better shrink should be helpful :)

Comment: Using `malloc(n * sizeof var)` instead of `malloc(n * sizeof type)` avoids the problem as in `e->weapons.weapons = malloc((xpm_q + 1) * sizeof *(e->weapons.weapons));`