# double free or corruption (faststop) after malloc() call

Tags: c

I have a small program to dynamically allocate array of pointer so user can enter an array of character as many time as they want. I created a struct with flexible array of pointer. The problem is when I try to `free(arrayPtr)` and `free(arrayPtr -> str[i])` from `malloc` call. It gives me the error **double free or corruption (faststop)**. But when I take them out. The program works fine but I still don't understand why. What happened behind the scene? Am I not supposed to use `free()` in this case?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdbool.h>



/* Get num */
char *getNum()
{

   char *_new, *num, c;

    int i;

    num =  malloc(sizeof(char));

    for (i = 0; (c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n'; i++)
    {
        _new = realloc(num, i + 2);         
        num = _new;
        num[i] = c;
    }

    if (c == '\n') 
        num[i] = '\0';

    num[i] = '\0';

    return num;
}


struct strHolder {
   int size;
   char *str[];
};


// Main
int main() 
{

      char *longNum;
      unsigned i = 0;
      struct strHolder *arrayPtr = malloc(sizeof (struct strHolder));

      for (i = 0; i < 6; i++)
          arrayPtr -> str[i] = malloc(sizeof (arrayPtr -> str[i]));

      i = 0;
      while (i < 6) {       

         printf("Enter %u number: ", i + 1);
         longNum = getNum();        
         arrayPtr -> str[i++] = longNum;    
      }




     for (i = 0; i < 6; i++)
         printf("\nnum is >> %s\n", arrayPtr -> str[i]);  

     for (i = 0; i < 6; i++) 
         free(arrayPtr -> str[i]);



     free(longNum);
     free(arrayPtr);

     return 0;

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to track down a "double free or corruption" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2902064/how-to-track-down-a-double-free-or-corruption-error)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You assign the pointer you get from `getNum()` to `longNum` and to an array element. At the end of the function you call `free()` on all the array elements, including the one containing the pointer you got from `getNum()`.

So far that's ok, but you additionally call `free(longNum)`, trying to free that memory a second time. It already got freed when you called `free()` on the corresponding array element.

Additionally there is a memory leak: The pointers originally in the array are never given to `free()` if they are overwritten by new pointers from `getNum()`. So the memory they reference is lost. This can be avoided by calling `free(arrayPtr -> str[i])` before assigning the new pointer returned by `getNum()`.

Comment: So do I need to free memory from struct too? Because I also call malloc() for it. Or freeing memory from element of the struct is good enough?

Answer (score 1):

when you did

```
free(arrayPtr -> str[i]);
```

you freed a pointer that you have assigned to it another pointer in the line

```
 arrayPtr -> str[i++] = longNum;
```

then you freed the same pointer again in line

```
free(longNum);
```