# why double free or corruption?

Tags: c++, qt, memory, try-catch, alloc

Every 1 second, function works.
my system the linux. Runs suddenly dies.

-----global-------

```
static int arrayNum[33000];
```

-------------------

```
 function(){
        unsigned short int**  US_INT;
try{
        US_INT= new unsigned short int*[255];
                for(int i = 0; i < 255; i++)
                {
                    US_INT[i] = new unsigned short int[128];
                    memset(US_INT[i], 0, sizeof(unsigned short int) * 128);
                }
        double x;
        double y;
        int cnt= 0;  
                int nArrayCount=0;
              for(int i = 0; i < 255; i++)
                {

                    for(int j=0;j<128;j++){

                        x=j;
        y=cnt
                        arrayNum[nArrayCount]=US_INT[i][j];

                        nArrayCount++;

                    }
                    cnt=cnt+(256/255); 

                }


         for(int i = 0; i < 255; i++)
                {
                    delete[] US_INT[i];
                }

                delete[] US_INT;
    }
catch (const std::bad_alloc&) {
            qDebug() << "alloc error";
            for(int i = 0; i < 255; i++)
                {
                    delete[] US_INT[i];
                }

                delete[] US_INT;
            }
}
```

When memory allocation fails, the exception handling. However, the program will die.
I made a mistake?
output:

> Error in `./TEST': double free or corruption (out): 0x34b00418

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to track down a "double free or corruption" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2902064/how-to-track-down-a-double-free-or-corruption-error)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Preface. It is strongly recommended to avoid raw pointers, like

```
unsigned short int** US_INT
```

Either use vector of vectors, or single-dimension vector and access elements like vec.at(X + Y*sizeX);

Why program dies?

Exception probably thrown in a middle of allocation of US_INT elements, so, part of array is valid, and part of array is uninitialized garbage. And in CATCH you are deleting pointers in whole array. Since deleting uninitialized pointer is undefined behavior - this is one of possible outcomes of UB here.

Comment: thank you. my testing...Memory allocation on the part of the flag. int count =0 ;       for(int i = 0; i < 255; i++)
                {
                    US_INT[i] = new unsigned short int[128];
                    memset(US_INT[i], 0, sizeof(unsigned short int) * 128);
                }                 <br> catch(){ for(int i=0;i<count;i++{}   //////Yet the result is unknown. Will continue to run.

Answer (score 0):

Your `catch` clause is broken. You start with `delete[] US_INT[i]` which isn't valid if the first `new` caused the exception. Fix: use `std::vector<>`. There's no reasonable way to figure out which of the 257 allocations threw, and therefore you don't know what to undo.

Comment: You could of course `std::fill()` null pointers into the array before allocating the real pointers, which would make a "reasonable way" to know what to undo.  Not that it's worth such effort when a much better approach is available.

Answer (score 0):

I can recomend same as the others, use `std::vector<>`!!! You will achieve the same on few lines of code which can everybody read.

> cnt=cnt+(256/255);

well `256/255` is equal to `1` so u can rewrite it to `++cnt;`