# Double Free or Corruption (out): 0x000000000154fc20 in C++

Tags: c++, vector, insertion-sort, double-free

i'm trying to do insertion sort over vectors in C++ but my ./a.out returns this: *** Error in `./insertion': double free or corruption (out): 0x000000000154fc20 ***

Don't know why is this happenning, i've seen other problems like this and it's always about the code, buy in my code i don't know what the problem is.

This is the code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>

using namespace std;


void insertion(vector<int> v){
  int tam = v.size();
  int key,j,i;
  for(i=1; i<tam; i++){
    key = v[i];
    j=i-1;
    while(j>=0 && v[j]>key){
      v[j+1] = v[j];
      j--;
    }
    v[j]=key;
  }
}

void print(vector<int> v){
  cout<<endl;
  for(int i = 0; i<v.size(); i++){
    cout<<i+1<<".\t"<<v[i]<<"\n";
  }
}

int main(){
  cout<<"----------------INSERTION SORT----------------\n\n";
  cout<<"\nPlease, fill the vector: \n\n";
  vector<int> v;
  int a;
  bool response = true;

  while(response){
      cout<<"\nEnter your number: ";
      cin>>a;
      v.push_back(a);
      cout<<"Another?(1/0): ";
      cin>>response;
      cout<<endl;
  }
  insertion(v);
  print(v);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: "and it's always about the code" - yes, it is.

Comment: learn to use a debugger

Comment: Valgrind will be of help here. compile with -g and do 
valgrind ./executable

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to track down a "double free or corruption" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2902064/how-to-track-down-a-double-free-or-corruption-error)

Answer (score 0):

In this snippet of your code, in insertion(),

```
j=i-1;
while(j>=0 && v[j]>key){
  v[j+1] = v[j];
  j--;
}
v[j]=key;
```

By definition, the `while` loop will terminate when `j<0` or `v[j]>key`.  When it terminates because `j<0`, assigning `v[j]=key` corrupts memory, since it is essentially `v[-1]=key`.

Comment: Thanks for the aclaration

Answer (score -1):

You have two options to fix that code:

1)

```
j=i-1;
    while(j>=0 && v[j]>key){
      v[j+1] = v[j];
      j--;
    v[j]=key;
    }
```

2)

```
j=i-1;
    while(j>=0 && v[j]>key){
      v[j+1] = v[j];
      j--;
    }
    v[j+1]=key;
```

Comment: I didn't notice that, also it's very strange to me that type of notification about an error, btw i'm starting to program C++ in the terminal of Ubuntu, maybe that's why i didn't understand that. Thanks a lot :D