# Double free or corruption (faststop)

Tags: c, struct, free

I was clearing memory from previous mallocs  and I  got this error :
***Error in `./prot': double free or corruption (fasttop)*** . I allocated memory for some structs and I got this error when trying to free them.
This are the structs I used:

```
struct ProdutoN
{
    char prod[MAXBUFFPROD];
    int altura;
    struct ProdutoN *esq;
    struct ProdutoN *dir;
};


struct ArrayProd
{
    ProdutoNP lista[26];
    int tamanho[26];
};
```

I created an incomplete type called `CatalogoProdutos` that points to the struct called `ArrayProd`. Inside that same struct I created an incomplete type called `ProdutoNP` that points to the struct called `ProdutoN` (which is an avl tree). This is how I have iniciated this structs :

```
void inicializa(CatalogoProdutos l)
{
    int i;
    l=(CatalogoProdutos)malloc(sizeof(struct ArrayProd));
    for(i=0;i<26;i++)
    {

        l->lista[i] = (ProdutoNP)malloc(sizeof(struct ProdutoN));
        l->lista[i] = NULL;
        l->tamanho[i]=0;

    }

}
```

This is how I tried to free this :

```
void freePNP (ProdutoNP lista)
{
    if (lista == NULL)
    return;

    free (lista->prod);
    freePNP (lista->esq);
    freePNP (lista->dir);

    free(lista);
}
void freeCP (CatalogoProdutos l)
{
    int i;

    if (l == NULL)
    return; 

    for (i = 0 ; i < 26 ; i++)
    freePNP(l->lista[i]);

    free(l);
}
```

Definitions of the incomplete types:

```
typedef struct ProdutoN *ProdutoNP;
typedef struct ArrayProd *CatalogoProdutos;
```

***What I am doing wrong ?***

Comment: `l->lista[i] = (ProdutoNP)malloc(sizeof(struct ProdutoN));
        l->lista[i] = NULL;` what is that suppossed to mean?

Comment: It would be useful to post the definitions of `ProdutoNP` and `CatalogoProdutos`.

Comment: @SouravGhosh i think he just wants to leak memory there :)

Comment: 1) Don't cast the result of `malloc`. 2) As I suspect the missing types are `typedef`ed pointers: Don't `typedef` pointers! This obfuscates the special semantics and eventually results in confusion.

Comment: `l=(CatalogoProdutos)malloc(sizeof(struct ArrayProd));` can't set to caller side variable. Because `l` is local variable.

Comment: There are lots of problems with this code.  `inicializa` is calling `malloc`, then immediately overwriting the pointers that were returned with `NULL`, losing them forever.  At best that's a memory leak.  `freePNP` is attempting to free `prod`, which is an array that is allocated as part of the containing structure.  This makes no sense.  Hint:  The calls to `free` should be in one-to-one correspondence with the calls to `malloc`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to track down a "double free or corruption" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2902064/how-to-track-down-a-double-free-or-corruption-error)

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to free the member of the struct that is not dynamically allocated.

```
free (lista->prod);
```