# Pop function linked list, glibc detected double free or corruption

Tags: c, linked-list, runtime-error, glibc

I am recieving this error when I attempt to run this program:

*** glibc detected *** ./a.out: double free or corruption (fasttop): 0x0000000001926070 ***

I attempted to create my own pop function in C and it is giving me the error above. I'm not sure where I went wrong.

```
struct node *pop(struct node *top, int *i)
{
  struct node *new_node = top;
  int count = 0;

  if ( new_node == NULL) {
    return top;
  }

  while ( new_node != NULL && (count < 1)) {
     *i = new_node->value;
     free(new_node);
     new_node = new_node->next;
     count++;
  }

  return new_node;
}
```

Comment: Where do you get the error? What do you get from the debugger? What have you tried to find out yourself?

Comment: 1) There is a need to update the caller side `top`. 2) `free(new_node);
     new_node = new_node->next;` : Do not use after release.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to track down a "double free or corruption" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2902064/how-to-track-down-a-double-free-or-corruption-error)

Answer (score 1):

```
free(new_node);
new_node = new_node->next;
```

You access the objct *after* you freed it. This invokes undefined behaviour. Once released, you must not acce the object.

Instead use a temporary pointer:

```
struct node *next = new_node->next;
free(new_node);
new_node = next;
```

That is the actual cause for your fault.

---

However, your code is far too complicated:

- The `if ( new_node == NULL)` is superfluous,as the `while` loop already tests for a *null pointer* and `new_node` is the same value as `top` anyway.
- `count` will make your loop interate at most once. So you don't need a loop at all.

See this:

```
struct node *pop(struct node *top, int *i)
{
    if ( top != NULL) {
        struct node *next = top->next;
        *i = top->value;
        free(top);
        top = next;
    }
    return top;
}
```

---

Note it is likely better to return the `pop`ed value and pass a *pointer to pointer* as `top` (`struct node **top`). That way you can use the result directly (presuming the stack is not empty, of course).