# Verifying Python reference count when sending list as parameter

Tags: python, c++, cpython

I have a C++ class that imports a Python module as a file and continuously calls a function for it before returning the received data:

```
ProgramLiveProcess::ProgramLiveProcess() {
    //Start Python to run the Program Python code
    Py_Initialize();

    //Import the Program live processing module
    program_live_processing_module = PyImport_ImportModule(MODULE_NAME);

    //Get the objects for the functions to call
    live_process = PyObject_GetAttrString(program_live_processing_module, "Program_LiveProcess");
}

//Creates Python list from intensities array
PyObject* ProgramLiveProcess::get_intensities_list(unsigned int intensities[INTENSITIES_DATA_SIZE]) {
    PyObject* tr = PyList_New(0);
    for (int i = 0; i < INTENSITIES_DATA_SIZE; i++) {
        PyObject* ta = PyLong_FromLong(intensities[i]);
        PyList_Append(tr, ta);
    }
    return tr;
}

//TODO: Make this actually work
//Frees objects in intensities Python list and the list itself
void ProgramLiveProcess::free_intensities_list(PyObject* i_list) {
    //std::cout << std::to_string(i_list->ob_refcnt) << std::endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < INTENSITIES_DATA_SIZE; i++) {
        PyObject* ta = PyList_GET_ITEM(i_list, i);
        Py_DECREF(ta);
    }
    Py_DECREF(i_list);
}

processed_data* ProgramLiveProcess::send_to_program_live_process(unsigned int intensities[INTENSITIES_DATA_SIZE], bool use_sensor_1) {
    //Call the Program_LiveProcess function
    PyObject* intensities_py = get_intensities_list(intensities);
    PyObject* calculate_args = PyTuple_Pack(2, intensities_py, use_sensor_1 ? Py_True : Py_False); //True or false depending on if using sensor 1 or 2
    PyObject* processed_data_tuple = PyObject_CallObject(live_process, calculate_args);
    Py_DECREF(calculate_args);
    free_intensities_list(intensities_py);

    //Get the data from the function
    PyObject* s0p = PyTuple_GetItem(processed_data_tuple, 0);
    PyObject* s0t = PyTuple_GetItem(processed_data_tuple, 1);

    //Return a struct containing the data
    processed_data* to_return = (processed_data*)malloc(PROCESSED_DATA_STRUCT_SIZE);
    if (to_return == NULL)
        return to_return;
    to_return->sensor_1_pressure = (float)PyFloat_AS_DOUBLE(s0p);
    to_return->sensor_1_temperature = (float)PyFloat_AS_DOUBLE(s0t);

    //Free python objects and return
    Py_DECREF(s0p);
    Py_DECREF(s0t);
    return to_return;
}

//Finalize the interpreter after freeing objects
ProgramLiveProcess::~ProgramLiveProcess() {
    Py_DECREF(live_process);
    free(live_process);
    Py_Finalize();
}
```

While the program receives data fine, I am getting inconsistencies in regards to memory leaks and crashes when run under different conditions. While I can't give a stack trace, I am wondering if I am doing something wrong in regards to creating or dereferencing Python objects. Often, the program only runs when I comment out the free_intensities_list call.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: C tag removed. Please note that C and C++ are different languages and should not be lumped together.

Comment: How come you can't give a stack trace?

Comment: Show the class body so we can easily see all the member variables.  In get_intensities_list() the entries in the list each have a ref count one too high because you are not Py_DECREF on the object in the for loop after you add it to the list.  You might be attempting to do odd cleanup that may be wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `free_intensities_list` function, you may be doing double frees. Consider using the `Py_XDECREF` instead.

```
void Py_DECREF(PyObject *o)
Decrement the reference count for object o. The object must not be NULL; if you aren’t sure that it isn’t NULL, use Py_XDECREF(). If the reference count reaches zero, the object’s type’s deallocation function (which must not be NULL) is invoked.
```

Source: https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/refcounting.html

Also, you can [use `MALLOC_CHECK`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2902064/how-to-track-down-a-double-free-or-corruption-error) to check for double frees.